# Laravel "Class \"App\\Models\\review\" not found" in production

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, digital-ocean

In my Laravel app there are 3 Models:
Movie, User, Review

**Review**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Review extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $hidden = ['user_id','movie_id','created_at','updated_at'];

    public function movie(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Movie::class);
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Movie**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Movie extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    public function review(){
        return $this->hasMany(review::class);
    }

    public function getAvg()
    {
        return $this->review()->average('rating');
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return $this->review()->count();
    }

    public function getBestRating()
    {
        return $this->review()->max('rating');
    }

    public function getWorstRating()
    {
        return $this->review()->min('rating');
    }
}
```

**User**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public function review()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
    }
}
```

**The query that doesn't work**

```
$movies = Movie::has('review')->with('review.user')->get();
```

**In localhost it works fine.** but after deploying in digitalOcean it returns **"Class "App\Models\review" not found"**

**I tried the console on digitalOcean:**

```
> Movie::has('review')->get()
[!] Aliasing 'Movie' to 'App\Models\Movie' for this Tinker session.

 ERROR Class "App\Models\review" not found in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php on line 775.
```

**but after running this in the same session:**

```
Review::all()
```

the previous Movie::has('review') works fine.

Why is that? Am I missing something?

Comment: `review != Review` ... case matters on a case sensitive filesystem; this is because of how autoloading works to find the class you are referencing

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely loading the classes from case sensitive file system hence why this issue is causing the issue. Whilst PHP class names are not case sensitive. It is considered good practice to them functions as they appear in their declaration

You need to change this line:

```
return $this->hasMany(review::class);
```

to

```
return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using different letter case. Class is defined as `Review` but you invoke `review`:

```
$this->hasMany(review::class);
```

Unlike variable names, neither class names nor function names are case sensitive in PHP:

```
class Example
{
    public static function test(): void
    {
        echo 'Hello, World!';
    }
}

// This works
eXaMpLe::TeSt();

// This doesn't: Warning: Undefined variable $FOO
$foo = 1;
echo $FOO;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0VfgE#v8.2.1)

However, Laravel is using a [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) compliant class auto-loader to locate and read the PHP files where classes are defined. Such auto-loader maps class names to file names, so whenever `App\Models\Review` is used in code, a filesystem path like `/your/project/libraries/path/App/Models/Review.php` is loaded. If any of your path components, either a directory or the file name, was created using a different case, whether it'll work or not will depend on the case-sensitive flag in the file system. If your file system is something like NTFS (typical on Windows) it'll decide that `review.php` and `Review.php` are the same file, so it'll work. In most Linux filesystems, it's actually allowed to have two different `review.php` and `Review.php` files, so they need to be considered different.

It's also worth nothing that the `::class` syntax is just a string feature and doesn't really trigger class autoloading:

```
// This is fine
echo Does\Not\Exist::class;
```

So you don't get the error right in the offending line, but later down the line when the class is eventually used.